# No response or error when fetching data with Vue.js using API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mutation, vue-props

I just started learning vue.js and need some help. I am trying to get answers from an external source using API when a question is typed in. But I am not getting any response and no error in the console. I am sure what the error might be.

This is the link to my code https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-dk71y

Comment: And then show the answer. I use watcher to know when the question is changing and check if the question typed in has question mark. If all these are true, then it should fetch the answer and display.

Comment: "question" is a variable in two different components. The watcher in the main file wont know if the question variable changes in the HelloWorld.vue component

Comment: I have updated my code @Bravo. I am sorry for the misconception. I have called the getAnswer function when created

Comment: `watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function(newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      console.log(this.question);
      this.answer = "Waiting for you to stop typing...";
      this.getAnswer()
    }
  },

  created: function(){
    this.getAnswer()
  },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there :) you just have to fix some problems in your code.

1. Since everything happens inside your `Hello World` component no need to try using props to pass `question` & `answer` in there. Just put all your logic inside the component.
2. Bind the `question` to the `input` with `v-model` directive (two-way binding) like: `<input v-model="question">`
3. You should call this.getAnswer() inside the `watcher`
4. and the `data` [should be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)

```js
data() {
  return {
   question: "",
   answer: "I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!"
  }
},
```

[Check this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-n8obf?fontsize=14)

*So your component **`Hellow World`** should be something like this:*

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
   <p>
    Ask a yes/no question:
    <input v-model="question">
  </p>
  <p>{{ answer }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data: () => ({
    question: "",
    answer: "I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!"
  }),

  watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function(newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      console.log(this.question);
      this.answer = "Waiting for you to stop typing...";
      this.getAnswer()
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getAnswer: function() {
      if (this.question.indexOf("?") === -1) {
        this.answer = "Questions usually contain a question mark";
        return;
      }
      this.answer = "Thinking...";
      let vm = this;
      axios
        .get(`https://yesno.wtf/api`)
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.answer = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          vm.answer = `Error connecting to the API ${error}`;
        });
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

*And your **`main.js`*** could be then just as simple as this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps